# Dynamically adding options and optgroups in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

With the following html:

```
<input type='hidden' id='cantseeme'>
```

I'm having no trouble creating a Select2 control dynamically, and adding my options:

```
// simplified example
var select2_ary = [];

select2_ary.push({
    id : "one",
    text : "one"
});
select2_ary.push({
    id : "two",
    text : "two"
});

$("#cantseeme").select2({
    placeholder : "Pick a number",
    data : select2_ary
});
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add `optgroups` this way. I found [this](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/58) discussion on github, and [this](http://www.eddiedillon.info/?p=453) article on a blog, but the former doesn't seem to discuss dynamic `optgroup` additions and I simply can't make any sense of the latter.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the answer buried inside the github discussion you linked to, the object structure for `optgroups` is as follows:

```
{
  id      : 1,
  text    : 'optgroup',
  children: [{
                id  : 2,
                text: 'child1'
             },
             {
                id      : 3,
                text    : 'nested optgroup', 
                children: [...]
             }]
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcUUG/44/)**

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks very much. I feel so dumb for missing that. Tbh, surprised that no one else has asked that before on here!

Comment: koala_dev, it looks like the fiddle you posted no longer works

Answer (score 25):

Yes, koala_dev's answer above is correct.  However, if you do not want option group headers to be selectable tags, then remove the "id" field from headers that you pass into select2.  Children[ ] items still need an "id" field to be selectable.  For example:

```
// `Header One` Is Selectable
[{
    id       : 0,
    text     : "Header One",
    children : [{
        id   : 0,
        text : "Item One"
    }, { 
        ...
    }]
}] 


// `Header One` Is Not Selectable
[{
    text     : "Header One",
    children : [{
        id   : 0,
        text : "Item One"
    }, { 
        ...
    }]
}]
```